How can I remove (or update) a Python .dist-info package?
I'm managing a cloud VM running Ubuntu 20.04 and have not worked with Python before. Sorry if this is a stupid question.
A security team is regularly scanning the servers and reported a vulnerable version of urllib3 in the folder /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3-a.b.c.dist-info.
As far as I know, Python came pre-installed with the Ubuntu image. I didn't actively install or specifically update Python.
What I tried is pip install --upgrade urllib3. But that only updated another urllib3 folder (I think) and not the .dist-info folder.
Would be awesome if someone could suggest what to do.

Simply delete the urllib3-a.b.c.dist-info folder? (Is it safe to do that?)
Can I update it in some way?
Update the Python version? (How?)


"Python came pre-installed with the Ubuntu image. I didn't actively install or specifically update Python" ... however, nothing in /usr/local comes pre-installed. Any files in it are specifically the result of you or whoever else is administering the system installing things there without using apt (likely via sudo pip install something)

I just spun up an Azure VM with an Ubuntu 20.04 image and /usr/local/lib/python3.8is right there. No action of myself or anyone else involved.

Then it's something added by Azure. Install Ubuntu from an ISO and you'll never see it there. You should raise a support ticket with Azure to ask them why it's there and what they recommend for it.
